# My loop only saves the result of last iteration

Tags: python, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

This is my data:

```
ts = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
ts.columns = ["TS"]
start_df = pd.Series([1,3,6])
end_df = pd.Series([2,7,10])
```

I have created the following function to clean up my loop, and a for loop to iterate over each element in ts and save according to the output of `check_if`.

```
def check_if(start, ts, end):
    if start <= ts <= end:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

ts["Flagg"] = np.nan
for ix, hour in enumerate (ts["TS"]):
    for jx, end in enumerate(end_df):
        ts["Flagg"][ix] = check_if(start_df[jx], hour, end_df[jx])
```

The problem is that my resulting `ts["Flagg"]` only saves the result of the last iteration, `start_df == 6` and `end_df == 10`. Is my logic in the loop completely of?

**Edit:**
**Expected output**

```
[0,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,0,0]
```

in column `ts["Flagg"]`.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Added expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with list comprehension for list of boolean mask and then `sum` it for count `True` values (are processes like `1`), thanks  @RafaelC for improvement:

```
ts['new'] = np.sum([ts['TS'].between(x, y) for x, y in zip(start_df, end_df)], axis=0)
print (ts)
    TS  new
0    0    0
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    4    1
5    5    1
6    6    2
7    7    2
8    8    1
9    9    1
10  10    1
11  11    0
12  12    0
```

**Details**:

```
print ([ts['TS'].between(x, y) for x, y in zip(start_df, end_df)])

[0     False
1      True
2      True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
Name: TS, dtype: bool, 0     False
1     False
2     False
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
Name: TS, dtype: bool, 0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11    False
12    False
Name: TS, dtype: bool
```

Comment: This works great! Can this be used for dates as well - could you please elaborate on the solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can create column (series, list) and then set it as column as jezrael pointed or create column with some initial values and then change them in loop:

```
ts["Flagg"] = [0 for _ in range(ts.size)]
for ix, hour in enumerate (ts["TS"]):
    for jx, end in enumerate(end_df):
        ts["Flagg"][ix] = check_if(start_df[jx], hour, end_df[jx])
```